# How to multiply This matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, math

so we have this matrix  `a=[1;2;3]` and we want to multiply it by itself `a*a`,

However Matlab doesn't do this multiplicaiton, and suggests using `a.^2` , but this only multiplies each member by itself `( 1;4;9 )`...

so how to multiply in Matlab `a*a (a^2)` ??

Greeed

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't multiply it by itself, because it's not square.

You can multiply it by its transpose, though:

```
a * a'
```

or:

```
a' * a
```

Which one you use depends on what you want.  But it sounds like you don't know what you want (otherwise there would be no question...)

Answer (score 1):

you can't multiply this two matrices, see why here :

[image]

In your case it is 3X1 matrix multiply by 3X1 matrix.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Illustration